# angular 2 child reference to variable into parent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to change the value of a variable or use a method in a parent component from a child component without using input and output

I try something like this but not working.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <button (click) = "rename()" > Rename Parent </button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'child'
  }

  rename() {
    App.name = 'Rename';
  }

}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <child> </child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

example here

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/PMM7BoQK6DSS57KArIaM?p=preview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Parent and Child Components Communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316896/angular2-parent-and-child-components-communication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input and Output are just made for this. It is, according to the Angular2 Documentation, made for communication between parent and child components.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
    <child [name]="this.name" (nameChanged)="this.name = $event"> </child>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>{{name}}</h2>
      <button (click) = "rename()" > Rename Parent </button>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class Child {

@Input() name:string;
@Output() nameChanged: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

  constructor() {
  }

  rename() {
    this.nameChanged.emit('Renamed');
  }

}
```

Alternatively you could inject a service into both parent and child component, which has some values that both parent and child can access and modify. But make sure to add that service to either only the parent component or only the AppModule, otherwise you would get 2 instances of your service.

Comment: "add that service to either only the parent component or only the AppModule, otherwise you would get 2 instances of your service" - can you elaborate on this? It's unclear to me what you mean

Comment: Okay Imagine you have two components. If you add your abcService as provider (in your @Component, you can define an array of providers) to each component, you will have two instances of this service and so you will have to data states and no sharing between the components. So make sure you either declare the service in your AppModule or only declare it in your parent component, your child component then would take the same instance

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't know declaring component providers created a new injector scoped to that component tree. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

That is @Output and @Input in Angular 2. 
Docs: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

- Another way that is Observable, Subject you can also inject data from a child component to root component or from a component to another component : See this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2qJxfi7370&list=PLFaW_8zE4amNEdKZOJD3P_GeV3Hgva7RD&index=10