# Observables: Angular2 Parent child communication

Tags: rxjs, angular2-routing, angular2-forms, angular2-observables

I have an angular2 form which is composed of a parent component and few child components.  I have a ReplaySubject in my service which emits when the parent needs to save something and the children subscribes to it and saves its elements. The parent component  need to know when all the children done saving. (We will still be in the form when the saving is done. So the children can't unsubscribe. ) How do I achieve this.?  Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

```
Parent component
----------------------
ngOnInit() {
    // TODO: listen to child events and check if respose from all children received ?? 
}
save() {
    console.log("Saving elements on parent component");
    this.formService.save$.next(this.job.id);
}

Child 1
---------------- 
ngOnInit() {
    this.formService.save$.subscribe(() =>
        console.log("Save elements on child1 component");
        // TODO: some event from here to say child 1 is done saving. ? 
    );
}


Child 2
---------------- 
ngOnInit() {
    this.formService.save$.subscribe(() =>
        console.log("Save elements on child2 component");
        // TODO: some event from here to say child 2 is done saving.  ?
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the parent has access to the child in it's template, the parent component could listen for a `onSaved` event that is emitted by the child components when they have finished saving.

In the **ChildComponent** you would define an output event:

`@Output() onSaved = new EventEmitter<any>();`

In the parent template you then listen to that event:

**ParentComponent.html**

`<child-component (onSaved)="childSaved()"></child-component>`

**ParentComponent.ts**

`onSaved() {
  // Action when all child components have indicated save is completed
}`

Angular documentation for this type of component communication is [here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event).

There's also some good answers on SO already - like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36316896/angular2-parent-and-child-components-communication?rq=1)

Comment: But how do we know that we got reply from all children

Comment: You'd have to track that in the `onSaved` method - presumably using a counter / increment to determine how many times that saved function was invoked.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Was wondering if there's a sophisticated way to do this using rxjs